# Archivos externos css no funcionan. DJango

Tags: css, django

Estoy realizando una sencilla web con `DJango` y cuando aplico la etiqueta `<style></style>` directamente en el archivo `html` no hay problemas, pero cuando extraigo el `css` a un archivo para que esté el código más limpio y ordenado ya no funciona.

Según he leído, he creado una carpeta static, dentro una llamada css y dentro de esta quiero guardar los diferentes archivos css.

Una vez hecho esto, cargo mediante `{% load static %}` la carpeta `static/css` y en el `head` declaro la ruta a mi fichero `css`.

Pero no me lo carga y me muestra el siguiente error:

> "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1660

Es decir, no encuentra mi fichero. A continuación adjunto mi código:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">

        <head>
            <title>
                {% block title%}{% endblock%}
            </title>

            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/main.css" %}">

        </head>
        <body>
            <h1> TÍTULO </h1>

            {% block content %}{% endblock%}
        </body>
    </html>
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Muchas gracias.

**Edit**

Leyendo más info he visto que a veces se añade en el archivo `settings.py` la siguiente línea, `STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]` pero no funciona tampoco.

Comment: Hola,¿ pudiste solucionarlo?, yo también tengo el mismo problema

Comment: Buenas, sube tu pregunta, avísame por aquí y si se resolverlo te ayudo!

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dices primero se debe de crear la carpeta `static`, quedaría algo así:

```
static
   └───css
```

Posterior a esto dentro del archivo settings.py se debe de poner:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Al final del archivo

---

Una vez realizado lo anterior, se debe de agregar al `head` de la plantilla lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```